# Error when performing test email sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk

**I am getting following error while performing test email send definition via SOAP API. Can anyone please explain to me what is the cause of this error and how can I resolve it?**

```
StatusCode   : 'Error', 
StatusMessage: 'The following email validation errors need addressed before the email can be sent. 
Error 1      : Script IF Statement Invalid
An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. 
See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: 

RowCount(LookupRows("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign)) 
MemberID: 106XXXX JobID: 0 The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. 

Function Call : 
LookupRows("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign) 
Attribute or Field Name: email_address 
Invalid Content: 
if RowCount(LookupRows("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign)) > 0 
        then\nRaiseError("Do not send to subscriber", true) 

Error 2       : Invalid Function Call
The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. 
Function Call : 
InsertDE("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign,"jobid",jobid,"emailname",@campaignName,"subscriberkey",subscriberkey) 
Attribute or Field Name: email_address 

Invalid Content: 
InsertDE("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign,"jobid",jobid,"emailname",@campaignName,"subscriberkey",subscriberkey) 

Error 3        : Invalid Function Call
The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client. 

Function Call  : 
InsertDE("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign,"jobid",jobid,"subscriberkey",subscriberkey) Attribute or Field Name: email_address 
Invalid Content : 
InsertDE("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign,"jobid",jobid,"subscriberkey",subscriberkey)
```

Answer (score 4):

The cause of this error is that your email HTML is invalid.  You can go into the User Interface inside of SFMC and edit and test email validation there.

The issues are as follows:

**Error 1**: *(I believe you want the personalization string `emailaddr` here)*

**Script IF Statement Invalid**
An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. 
See inner exception for detail.

Script Expression:
`RowCount(LookupRows("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign))`
MemberID: 106XXXX
JobID: 0
Reason: The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.

**Function Call:**
 
`LookupRows("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign)`
 
Attribute or Field Name: email_address
 
**Invalid Content:**

```
if RowCount(LookupRows("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign)) > 0 
then\nRaiseError("Do not send to subscriber", true)
```

**Error 2**: *(same as #1 - replace `email_address` with `emailaddr`)*

**Invalid Function Call**
The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.

**Function Call :**
 
`InsertDE("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign,"jobid",jobid,"emailname",@campaignName,"subscriberkey",subscriberkey)`
Attribute or Field Name: email_address 

**Invalid Content:**

```
InsertDE("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign,"jobid",jobid,"emailname",@campaignName,"subscriberkey",subscriberkey)
```

**Error 3**: *(same as #1 - replace `email_address` with `emailaddr`)*

**Invalid Function Call**
The specified attribute or custom object field name was not found for this client.

**Function Call**: 
`InsertDE("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign,"jobid",jobid,"subscriberkey",subscriberkey)`
Attribute or Field Name: email_address

**Invalid Content**:

```
InsertDE("TEST","emailaddress",email_address,"campaign_id",@ConcatenatedCampaign,"jobid",jobid,"subscriberkey",subscriberkey)
```

It would appear that the personalization string of `email_address` does not exist inside the list/DE that you are using. All personalization strings are required to have matching fields or they throw errors.  A way to handle this is by utilizing the `AttributeValue()` function - but as this is the primary key, it would still error if empty.

Your best bet is to either use the `emailaddr` personalization string which will pull in the sendable email address field of current subscriber or to look inside your DE or List for the Email Address value that should be there and then add it instead of `email_address`.

For example (DE has field emailaddress):

```
%%[
SET @emailaddress = AttributeValue('emailaddress')
RowCount(LookupRows("TEST", "emailaddress", @emailaddress, "campaign_id", @ConcatenatedCampaign))
]%%
```